# Not able to click on checkbox Since that content of the checkbox is having url

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I tried many ways to click on checkbox but it opens the url when i try to click
I tried with class , name and for object but it opens the url and ::before and ::after highlights the particular checkbox [::before][1]

Comment: You need to share the code that you have written for answers/solutions here. Also if possible, the website link to inspect.

Answer (score 0):

A checkbox is a checkbox, no matter what content appears to the left or right.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("Your CSS selector here")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("Your xpath expression here"))click();
```

Please share your code, or the error you get